# Getting a Radius of Positions around a Certain Point

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I need to get the location of points surrounding a certain point. e.i. :

[x] [x] [**2**] [x] [x]

[x] [**2**] [**1**] [**2**] [x]

[**2**] [**1**] [**c**] [**1**] [**2**]

[x] [**2**] [**1**] [**2**] [x]

[x] [x] [**2**] [x] [x]
*(1 = a radius of 1, 2 = a radius of 2, c = center point)*

Right now I am getting the coordinates with *`(CCSprite = [array objectAtIndex:i] CGPoint pos = sprite.position`)* `(pos.x+1,pos.y)`, `(pos.x-1,pos.y)`, `(pos.x,pos.y+1)`, `(pos.x,pos.y-1)` and I add those to the `array` and then run through the `for` loop the number of times equal to the radius. But I'm having trouble not adding positions that are already in the array and getting it to work properly for a radius larger than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself but thanks to those who helped. This assumes in your final array you have the center coordinate added at index 0. The end result will be an array (attackableTiles in this case) that contains CCSprites (from which you can get coordinates) with positions surround a center point out to a certain radius. As depicted in my original question.

```
int timesThrough = 0;
int pRange = (the desired radius)
//(attackableTiles and goingToAddTiles are both NSMutableArrays)
if (timesThrough < pRange) {
        for (int i = 0; i < attackableTiles.count; i++) {
            if (attackableTiles.count < ((pRange*pRange) +((pRange+1)*(pRange+1)))) {
                CCSprite * tile = [attackableTiles objectAtIndex:i];
                CGPoint pos = [self tileCoordForPosition:tile.position];
                CGPoint posXUp1 = ccp(pos.x+1, pos.y);
                CGPoint posXDown1 = ccp(pos.x-1, pos.y);
                CGPoint posYUp1 = ccp(pos.x, pos.y+1);
                CGPoint posYDown1 = ccp(pos.x, pos.y-1);
                CCSprite * addingTileXUp1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon-72.png"];
                addingTileXUp1.position = [self positionForTileCoord:posXUp1];
                CCSprite * addingTileXDown1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon-72.png"];
                addingTileXDown1.position = [self positionForTileCoord:posXDown1];
                CCSprite * addingTileYUp1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon-72.png"];
                addingTileYUp1.position = [self positionForTileCoord:posYUp1];
                CCSprite * addingTileYDown1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon-72.png"];
                addingTileYDown1.position = [self positionForTileCoord:posYDown1];

                addedXUp1 = FALSE;
                addedYUp1 = FALSE;
                addedXDown1 = FALSE;
                addedYDown1 = FALSE;

                for (int i = 0; i < attackableTiles.count; i++) {
                        CCSprite * tile = [attackableTiles objectAtIndex:i];
                        if (CGPointEqualToPoint(tile.position, addingTileXUp1.position)) {
                            addedXUp1 = TRUE;
                        }    
                }
                if (!addedXUp1) {
                    [goingToAddTiles addObject:addingTileXUp1];
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < attackableTiles.count; i++) {
                    CCSprite * tile = [attackableTiles objectAtIndex:i];
                    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(tile.position, addingTileYUp1.position)) {
                        addedYUp1 = TRUE;
                    }
                }
                if (!addedYUp1) {
                    [goingToAddTiles addObject:addingTileYUp1];
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < attackableTiles.count; i++) {
                    CCSprite * tile = [attackableTiles objectAtIndex:i];
                    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(tile.position, addingTileXDown1.position)) {
                        addedXDown1 = TRUE;
                    }
                }
                if (!addedXDown1) {
                    [goingToAddTiles addObject:addingTileXDown1];
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < attackableTiles.count; i++) {
                    CCSprite * tile = [attackableTiles objectAtIndex:i];
                    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(tile.position, addingTileYDown1.position)) {
                        addedYDown1 = TRUE;
                    }
                }
                if (!addedYDown1) {
                    [goingToAddTiles addObject:addingTileYDown1];
                }

                [attackableTiles addObjectsFromArray:goingToAddTiles];
                [goingToAddTiles removeAllObjects];
                timesThrough++;

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this diagram, which shows the offsets for radius 3:

[image: Radius 3 diagram]

I have grouped the cells into four groups, labeled "Quadrant 1" through "Quadrant 4".  Notice that in each group, all of the x offsets have the same sign, and all of the y offsets have the same sign.  In all 12 cells, `abs(x) + abs(y) = radius`.  So, given all that, we can write a loop to visit all cells at radius 3:

```
int radius = 3;
for (int i = 1; i < radius; ++i) {
    int j = radius - i;
    [self visitCellAtXOffset:+j yOffset:+i]; // quadrant 1
    [self visitCellAtXOffset:-i yOffset:+j]; // quadrant 2
    [self visitCellAtXOffset:-j yOffset:-i]; // quadrant 3
    [self visitCellAtXOffset:+i yOffset:-j]; // quadrant 4
}
```

Of course you can loop radius from 1 to whatever you need.  If you also want to visit the center cell (at offset 0,0), do it with a separate call outside the loop.

Comment: What does `[self visitCellAtXOffset:a yOffset:b];` do? is that a built in function?

Comment: And I not only need to get the coordinates of the edge of the radius, i need to get the inside ones as well, not including the center.

Comment: Replace `visitCellAtXOffset:yOffset:` with whatever you need to do at each cell.  As for "I need to get the inside ones as well", read the last sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're actually looking for here is the *Manhattan distance* for every point on the grid:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry

You can calculate it for any two points as simply `abs( x1 - x2 ) + abs( y1 - y2 )`, so there's no need to repeat the calculation for each radius. Just keep x1,y1 fixed and loop through all the x2,y2 points.

If you're looking for something actually circular, the *Euclidean distance* is given by `sqrt( (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2) )`